# Calculate height of each node of a general tree stored as array of vectors C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have stored a tree in the form of an array of vectors in C++ such that the first column of each row consists of the total number of child nodes of that node and then subsequent columns of each row consist of an index of all the child nodes of that node.

```
vector <long long int> nodes[N];
```

For example - There are `N=8` nodes and if `v` is the immediate child of `u`, given the nodes of the tree are

```
u v
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
4 6
4 7
6 8
```

then the array of vectors `nodes` will be

```
0. 2 2 3
1. 2 4 5
2. 0
3. 2 6 7
4. 0
5. 1 8
6. 0
7. 0
```

Now, I want to save the height of each node in a new array of size N.
How can I develop an algorithm for this?

Comment: I guess there is no need of storing the number of children in the first column of every row because the `nodes[i].size()` is that same number.

Comment: @risingStark Yes, it is redundant but I did it for my convenience.

Comment: I also think that the adjacency list you mentioned above is wrong for index `3`. It should be `3. 2 6 7`. You can visualize your graph here https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/

Comment: @risingStark Thank You. That was a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function which can calculate the height of every node in the tree.

It is a simple DFS of tree with root as `0`.

```
int height(vector<int> nodes[], vector<int> &arr, int u, int p){
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=nodes[u][0];i++){
        if(nodes[u][i]!=p){
            ans=max(ans, height(nodes, arr, nodes[u][i], u));
        }
    }
    return arr[u] = 1 + ans;
}
```

This function can be called as follows: `height(nodes, arr, 0, -1)` where `arr` is an empty vector of size `n` i.e., `vector<int> arr(n, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, I could devise an iterative solution.

```
int heights[N] = {0};
        
        for(long long int i = N-1;i>=0;i--){
            
            int max = 0;
            int no_child = nodes[i][0];
            
            for(int j=1;j<=no_child;j++){
                if(heights[nodes[i][j]] > max){
                    max = heights[nodes[i][j]];
                }
            }
            
            max++;
            heights[i] = max;
        }
```